# iOS NSURL returning nil on valid URL

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I've entered the URL `http://localhost:8080/a?a=1\\tb?b=2` on the Safari it worked as expected but when using NSURL URLWithString it return nil.
(The server also require `\t` character)

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8080/a?a=1\\tb?b=2"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to percent-encode your values in the URL string. When it’s received by the server, it will decode this percent-encoded string in the URL into the desired value.

But rather than percent-encoding yourself, you can use `NSURLComponents`. For example, if you want `a` to have the value of `@"1\\tb"`, you can do:

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"http://localhost:8080"];
components.queryItems = @[
    [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"a" value:@"1\\tb"],
    [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"b" value:@"2"]
];
NSURL *url = components.URL;
```

Yielding:

```
http://localhost:8080?a=1%5Ctb&b=2
```

Or, if you wanted it to have the tab character in the value associated with `a` (i.e. `%09`):

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"http://localhost:8080"];
components.queryItems = @[
    [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"a" value:@"1\tb"],
    [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"b" value:@"2"]
];
NSURL *url = components.URL;
```

Yielding:

```
http://localhost:8080?a=1%09b&b=2
```

It just depends upon whether your server is expecting two characters, the `\` followed by `t` (the first example) or the single `\t` character (the second example). Either way, the respective use of `NSURLComponents` will take care of the percent-encoding for you, and your server will decode it.

---

For what it’s worth, the one caveat is the `+` character, which `NSURLComponents` won’t percent-encode for you (because, technically, a `+` character is allowed in a URL query). The problem is that the `+` character is interpreted as a space character by most web servers (per the `x-www-form-urlencoded` [spec](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_8.html#SEC8.2.1)). If you need to pass a literal `+` character, you might want to replace those `+` characters, as advised by Apple:

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"http://localhost:8080"];
components.queryItems = @[
    [NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"q" value:@"Romeo+Juliet"]
];
components.percentEncodedQuery = [components.percentEncodedQuery stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
NSURL *url = components.URL;
```

Comment: I've understood problem, but how to make NSURL allow \ (backslash) character? The server (can't be changed) required to split params based on "\t" so percent-encoding make it unable to split. I see that when enter URL on Chrome and Safari it work as expected.

Comment: “so percent-encoding make it unable to split” ... No, the server, when it receives the URL, automatically percent-decodes it (assuming we’re talking about the URL of the request itself, not some URL buried in the payload). So, if you’re using, for example, `$_REQUEST['a']`, that percent encoding is gone. But you can’t change the behavior of `NSURL`. That’s how it works. So, if you’re building a `NSURL` for creation of a request, you have to percent encode it (and, again, the server will decode it for you).